# How can I read user input text from a textfield and write it to a text file in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nsstring

Is there a way to write a string , which is read from text field, to a .txt file?

```
NSString *input = [textfield text];

NSString *path = @"myText.txt";

[input writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a path, basically where to save the file. 
This code will find the Documents folder

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( 
            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentDirPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
```

Here is the code I use to read and write files.

```
-(void)writeFileToDisk:(id)data 
{ 
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( 
            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentDirPath = [path objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *fileName = @"MyFileName.txt"; 

    NSString *fileAndPath = [documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]; 

    [data writeToFile:fileAndPath atomically:YES]; 
} 

-(void)readFileFromDisk 
{ 
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( 
            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentDirPath = [path objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *fileName = @"MyFileName.txt"; 

    NSString *fileAndPath = [documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]; 

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileAndPath]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",array); 
    [array release]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ultimately that *is* the way; but there's a number of other steps you do in order to get from start to finish (you need to have textfield connected to an IBOutlet or in some other way accessible; the path where myText.txt is writing to needs to be writable and therefore you'd probably need to have a longer, more precise path than just the filename; you'd probably need to also send in an actual error parameter that could be set so you could look at the errors being returned when the writeToFile call fails the first few times you run this code).